# Divisibility Demonstrations (Propositions)

Tags: divisibility

I already have a demonstration, but need a second opinion on how to demonstrate this:
Being $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, If $a^2|b^3$, then $a|b$

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because $2\ne3$ but the question that duplicates this one says $a^n|b^n$ which have the same power.

Comment: The second question that duplicates this one obviously doesn't. There is no mention of irrationality in the OP.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I agree with the above comments.  Unlike the proposed duplicate, the claim in this question is false; e.g., $16^2\mid8^3,$ but $16\not\mid8$

Comment: @KamalSaleh Please be patient. The dupe list was being edited and niw has exact dupes. Please retract your vote and delete the comment (so as now to mislead voters)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Please be patient. The dupe list was being edited and niw has exact dupes. Please retract your vote and delete the comment (so as now to mislead voters)

Comment: Please check for possible typos in your exponents: with $b^2$ it is true and with $b^3$ it is false. I've added dupe links for both cases (there are *many* more too).

Comment: I agree that one of the duplicates on the edited list is now a genuine duplicate, so I retracted my reopen vote